# How to check if value is None

Tags: python, django

I want to check if the "nilai" is None/Null

```
cursor.execute('SELECT s.kode_ktg_id,(SUM(n.nilai_angka * S.nilai_mk)/SUM(s.nilai_mk)) as nilai_ktg FROM mahasiswa_khs k, mahasiswa_convert_nilai n, mata_kuliah_si s WHERE k.nilai = n.nilai_huruf AND k.nim = "%s" AND k.kode = s.kode GROUP BY s.kode_ktg_id',[nim])
nilai = cursor.fetchall()
```

I check with this

```
if nilai[0] is None:
```

But I got error tuple index out of range

Comment: It means that `nilai` is empty...

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The only time a subscript of `0` is out of range, is when the sequence is empty.  You have some problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Please take the time to write a useful question if you expect a useful answer. Checking for a Null value is surely a trivial thing, so why do you ask how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `nilai` is an *empty* tuple, since it returned *no* records.

You can check if it is empty with:

```
if not nilai:
    # no records
else:
    # at least one record
```

That being said, in Django you can make use of the Django ORM, which is often safer, and wraps elements in model objects.

Comment: Thank you, I want ask something.
I want to make an insert like this
cek2 = cursor.execute('INSERT INTO mahasiswa_ktg_mhs (nim,nilai_cdg) VALUES (%s,%s)',[nim,cdg])

But why in my table has ' in every row of nim?
'2305002 <--- like this

Comment: Done, Thankyou very much